# Very slow internet over ethernet

Tags: linux, windows, networking, router, ethernet

My roomates (5 people including me) and I are currently using the router provided by our provider (Rogers). When five computers are all connected via ethernet, the internet speed is intolerably slow (< 100 KB/s). However, the internet speed over Wi-Fi is still normal (~ 20 MB/s). I have tested local throughput via iperf3, and it gives normal results (~ 950 Mbit/sec).

What could be causing this strange problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you test the local throughput over Wi-Fi or LAN?

Comment: @BilfredKerman via LAN.

Comment: What's the internet speed when just one device is connected, over LAN?

Comment: It fluctuates between 15-30 MB/s. It is also like this when a few other devices are connected. Even with all 5 connected, this still only happen sometime; it is not always reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

From the other information you've provided, the answer is as simple as - someone else is using a **lot** of the bandwidth. Like a Steam Update, or a Windows Update, and the modem prioritises the traffic so that everyone else gets super slow internet while that one person gets priority.

Comment: I have tested Wi-Fi internet throughput when I could reproduce the slow speed; the Wi-Fi speed is normal as I have stated (20-30 MB/s).

Comment: Which means the modem prioritises Wi-Fi more than LAN...

Comment: To the point where it would practically take all bandwidth from LAN as soon as someone does anything on Wi-Fi? To be fair WMM QoS for Wi-Fi isn't even turned on.

Comment: Slow internet really has a lot of variables. Most of the time, it's related to load. Could be load within the connection (someone downloading something), load balancing stuffing up, the router could be overloading and slowing down, refusing connections till it recovers. If it's a host-provided modem, it most likely isn't very powerful in terms of computer power, which means it could easily be being overloaded. Or you could be a victim of a DoS/DDoS attack. You could request a new IPv4 address from your provider, if you are in fact being DoS'd

Comment: If it's a load issue or D?DoS it wouldn't explain why Wi-Fi would still maintain the normal internet speed, even when I can reproduce the slow speed via ethernet. I do not believe the router has separate processors for ethernet and Wi-Fi.

Comment: It was a list of issues that are usually related to slow internet. Mind you, not a full list. And seeing as Wi-Fi still works fine, the modem clearly isn't overloaded, nor is it being DoS'd.  Which means it has to be a load balancing stuff up from within the modem. It clearly prioritises Wi-Fi over LAN, and certain LAN applications over others.

Answer (score 1):

I had the unique experience of a bad cable causing a lot of retransmission from one pc to the router. This would slow my network to a crawl when my cable was tugged on a little. Even a cable that is not plugged in all the way can intermittently  connect and disconnect resulting  in a slow network as packets are retransmitted. Look at the network utilization of each pc when this is happening as well as the task manager (in Windows) to look for processes that have gone haywire.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one, try moving all the ports plugged into the LAN interface onto a switch and uplink the switch to your router.  (This has helped me in a similar scenario).

A lot of routers are underpowered - and while it looks like the ethernet ports form a switch, in most cases they are actually seperate ports which are bridged into a switch, and forwarded in the routers firmware.  Offloading to a dedicated switch will eliminate the possibility that heavy communications within your network are overloading the routers ethernet ports and slowing things down.